# Xamarin YouTube Player Library

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, youtube

I am using Xamarin to develop a cross-platform mobile app for both Android and iPhone. In my app I have to programmatically play a YouTube video. For the Android part I used a bind version of the official YouTube library and I have finished it without problem.

For the iPhone part I am unable to find a working library that could let me programmatically play the YouTube video. 
I have tried the YouTube iframe API sample code from the following link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

The code I used is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the browser from my desktop, it auto-start the video after it is loaded using the startVideo() method. It works perfectly fine on desktop browser until I bring it to the iOS web view. It can load the video but it does not auto-start, which is one of our customer's requirement.

I understand that there are iOS library which could do the auto-play feature, but as I lack the knowledge on iOS native development, I am unable to do the iOS binding process.

I have tried other solutions like the followings:
https://github.com/afalz/YTHelper
https://github.com/nodoid/YoutubeBindings/tree/master/GoogleYoutube
But none of the above could work.

Any suggestion on how to do the auto-play feature in Xamarin?

Comment: working on a binding for YTHelper, couldn't make it work while native solution (xcode + ythelper pod) works fine. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Alexey sorry for the late reply. I explained to my customer about the technical difficulty I faced and our company lacks native iOS developer to overcome the situation. They accepted it and therefore I didn't implement the autoplay function in iOS part. This question is still not resolved. Sorry for letting you down.

Comment: no worries, thanks for the update